# SQL Query View from two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two queries, both have same columns and i want to view both queries columns in parallel position.
e.g

1 query out put is 2 column   "|Amount| Total|"

2 query out put is 2 column   "|Amount| Total|"

result required as "|Amount| Total| Amount| Total|"
please help
Thanks

Comment: And what are the rules how to combine the rows? Do both queries always yield the same number of rows? Do you want to combine each row of the first with each row of the second? Or zip them? Or shuffle?  Please give some example data and show what you have tried so far and what does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I will asume you have something like this
Select Amount,  Total from table1
Select Amount, Total from table 2

You can  try this:

Select table1.Amount,table1.Total,Table2. Amount, table2.Total 
From table1, table2

(this will create duplicity of data)

Hope  works  for you